# ArcGIS Server not updating Active Directory Changes?

Tags: arcgis-server, directory

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.4 on Windows Server 2012 r2

I have users from active directory with built in roles on the server.

organization policy is to force users to change their AD passwords every 3 months, when this happens ArcGIS Server is not picking up these changes (sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't) what is causing this non-consistent  event and how can I fix it?

my temp solution was to re-load the AD connection into the server every time a user creates a work order for this issue. there must be a better way

Comment: Have you tried clearing out a user's browser cache whenever they report ArcGIS Server hasn't picked up their new password?

Also, are you able to successfully test the identity store ?
https://<hostname.domain.com>/<WebAdaptor>/admin/security/config/testIdentityStore

Comment: Yes I can test identity store, and no I have cleared thebrowser cache I will be sure to do so the next time this happens.

Comment: One of the issues was I would have the PSA account disabled and my 
 personal account (admin) would not be able to login because ArcServer did not recognize the password. I had no access to the admin page... I had to go to the server installation directory on the machine and use the reset PSA enabled .py script (it worked but huge inconvenience)